# Why is the user_id returned from Google Account API different from the user_id on Google plus and how do I access the former with oauth 2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

- I login on a google appengine app where the authentication service is 'Google Accounts API' (default)
- I get the user_id by invoking users.get_current_user().user_id()
- Then I go to play on [openAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) and get a token to query for the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
- From that second call I get a different user_id from the one retrieved from Google Accounts API.

Why is this, and how do I get the 'Google Accounts API' using the oauth2 flow? I didn't manage to find an appropriate scope.

Comment: You can't.  There is no way to link the two.  You'll need to get both ids for each user and link them yourself.

Comment: Why didn't you post that as an answer? Because it is the answer indeed. @JeffO'Neill

Comment: Because I answered this question before so this is a duplicate question, but I can't find the other one...